# Read .txt file value after a certain string (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, text-files, finite-element-analysis

I'm trying to obtain the displacements of a node from an FEA .txt results file using matlab.  I want to search for the node (e.g. 5151) and then read the displacements, the problem is the node is mentioned a couple of times before getting to the deformations.
The part of the results I'm interested in looks like this......

```
                                       N O D E   O U T P U T



   THE FOLLOWING TABLE IS PRINTED FOR NODES BELONGING TO NODE SET ASSEMBLY_TIP_NODES


   NODE FOOT-   U1          U2          U3          UR1         UR2         UR3      
        NOTE

   5101      2.6105E-03 -1.1943E-02  6.0023E-03 -8.6770E-02 -1.6432E-02 -1.1048E-02 
   5102      2.5224E-03 -1.1267E-02  5.6868E-03 -8.6763E-02 -1.6390E-02 -1.0943E-02 
   5103      2.4340E-03 -1.0589E-02  5.3709E-03 -8.6725E-02 -1.6269E-02 -1.0666E-02 
   5104      2.3455E-03 -9.9121E-03  5.0549E-03 -8.6542E-02 -1.6052E-02 -1.0267E-02 
   5105      2.2575E-03 -9.2374E-03  4.7396E-03 -8.6041E-02 -1.5708E-02 -9.7843E-03 
   5106      2.1710E-03 -8.5682E-03  4.4262E-03 -8.5111E-02 -1.5217E-02 -9.2317E-03 
   5107      2.0869E-03 -7.9085E-03  4.1164E-03 -8.3688E-02 -1.4585E-02 -8.6334E-03 
   5108      2.0063E-03 -7.2623E-03  3.8120E-03 -8.1750E-02 -1.3825E-02 -8.0049E-03 
   5109      1.9299E-03 -6.6336E-03  3.5150E-03 -7.9308E-02 -1.2958E-02 -7.3631E-03 
   5110      1.8586E-03 -6.0265E-03  3.2271E-03 -7.6400E-02 -1.2011E-02 -6.7206E-03 
   5111      1.7928E-03 -5.4442E-03  2.9500E-03 -7.3084E-02 -1.1010E-02 -6.0892E-03 
   5112      1.7329E-03 -4.8897E-03  2.6851E-03 -6.9435E-02 -9.9818E-03 -5.4777E-03 
   5113      1.6791E-03 -4.3652E-03  2.4334E-03 -6.5533E-02 -8.9528E-03 -4.8933E-03
```

etc, so what I want to do is search for a unique string ' N O D E   O U T P U T' and then search for '5151' and import its displacements into an array.

Example output
nodeDisp = 1.6791E-03 -4.3652E-03  2.4334E-03 -6.5533E-02 -8.9528E-03 -4.8933E-03

Comment: give an output example .

Comment: You might be better off if you pre-process the text file first to get rid of the text and headings. Then you can read the columns into an array easily.

Comment: Question edited to include output. Essentially I just want the displacements of the desired node saved into an array to be used later on in the data processing.